# CentOS MySQL Problems

Tags: centos, mysql

Im having trouble with MySQL on my centos5 server. When I try to connect to the server I receive the following message

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have noticed when I run `service mysqld stop` This returns the stopping ok message. However when I run afterwards `service mysqld status`
It sends back

```
mysqld (pid 20600) is running...
```

I then ran the  status command a few more time and noticed the PID is constantly increasing

```
mysqld (pid 21835) is running...
[root@s15333475 log]# service mysqld status
mysqld (pid 21927) is running...
[root@s15333475 log]# service mysqld status
mysqld (pid 21988) is running...
[root@s15333475 log]# service mysqld status
mysqld (pid 21988) is running...
[root@s15333475 log]# service mysqld status
mysqld (pid 22079) is running...
[root@s15333475 log]# service mysqld status
mysqld (pid 22079) is running...
```

This is still coming up even though I have stopped the service

Here is the output from ps

```
root 582 1 4 16:41 ? 00:06:57 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql mysql 6481 582 0 19:17 ? 00:00:00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Hopefully someone can help!

Cheers

Comment: Output from a `ps -ef | grep mysqld` might help

Comment: `root       582     1  4 16:41 ?        00:06:57 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
mysql     6481   582  0 19:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
root      6499  1389  0 19:17 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mysqld` @Foosh

Comment: Check logs for errors `/var/log/mysqld.log`